# SP.RequestExecutor Object doesn't support property or method 'executeQueryAsync'

Tags: office-365

I'm trying to write a simple SP Hosted WebPart that makes a rest call to Yammer but when I try making a call with SP.RequestExecutor.executeQueryAsync(), I get an error message:  Object doesn't support property or method 'executeQueryAsync'

```
function () {
    //Get the URI decoded SharePoint site url from the SPHostUrl parameter.
    var spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    var appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));

    execOperation();
    yammerOperation(appWebUrl);

    // Function to execute SP basic operations.
    function execOperation() {
        // SP Call - get context and then username
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        getUserName();           
    }

    // Function to execute Yammer operations
    function yammerOperation(appWebUrl) {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);

        executor.executeQueryAsync(
            {
                url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/for_user/xxxxxxxx.json",
                method: "GET",
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: successHandler,
                error: errorHandler
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs since [SP.RequestExecutor object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx) does not contain [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn735929.aspx) `executeQueryAsync`.

Probably you meant [SP.RequestExecutor.executeAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn735920.aspx), if so, replace the line

```
executor.executeQueryAsync(...)
```

with

```
executor.executeAsync(...)
```